# How to pass a callback to a link without using bind

Tags: reactjs

React is generating thousands of console warnings when I render a link (thousands of times) that uses `.bind` for the onMouseOut and onMouseOver callbacks.

```
<a href={'http://localhost:8000/display' + this.props.user_id} onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver.bind(null)}>show user</a>
```

The callback `handleMouseOver` will not fire if I don't use `bind`, however, as mentioned, if I do use bind, it generates a warning for each time the link is created (which is thousands of times)

How can I pass a callback to this link without generating the warning?

```
Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See module.exports
```

Comment: Are you using an ES6 class decoration or are you extending from a React Component? If you're extending from a React component you don't need to add bindings.

Comment: I'm not using ES6 so I guess I am "extending from a React Component" but I'm not sure what you mean by "extending from".

Comment: I think Tyler's wording was a little off. If you use ES6 classes to build components you have to bind your methods to the class (just like in normal JS). If you're using the `createClass()` method you don't have to bind the context. However, that's not your issue here, as you're trying to bind arguments to the method, not bind a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update, your current issue is happening because you're using `.bind()` but not providing any arguments to apply to the function. Because React binds the context for you, `.bind(null)` is completely useless. You should either add some arguments to the call (`.bind(null, arg1, arg2)`) or remove it completely and just use `this.handleMouseOver`.

---

The error is happening because you're binding to `this` instead of `null`. React wants to make it blatantly obvious that it is doing the binding for you - you don't have to worry about it. Change `.bind(this, report)` to `.bind(null, report)` and the warning will go away.

Comment: anytime I pass a function to a component, I now bind as you specify `.bind(null, report)` but the (thousands of) warning messages aren't going away (and it doesn't appear to be a cache issue).

Comment: Are you sure the warning is caused by this particular code? Maybe it's somewhere else in your code, or even in a third party library.

Comment: ok, you were right. It wasn't that part of the code. It's only the links that are generating the warning when I bind a callback to the onMouseOver and onMouseOut events. I updated the OP if you have time to look.